# how to downgrade in command line for ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

I am using OS 12.04 version, but using `upgrade` command results in the desktop being changed for the new version 13.04.

How do I downgrade to the old version using the command-line?

From this:

```
root@metal004:~# lsb_release -a
  No LSB modules are available.
  Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
  Description:  Ubuntu 13.04
  Release:  13.04
  Codename: raring
```

To:

```
root@metal004:~# lsb_release -a
  No LSB modules are available.
  Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
  Description:  Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
  Release:  12.04
  Codename: precise
```

Comment: helpful link, http://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version

Answer (score 0):

It is just not supported. Neither it's supported in Debian, nor Fedora, nor Windows, nor Mac, nor any OS that supports downgrading. It's [like Sergey said](https://askubuntu.com/a/77738/169736)

> You can't turn mince back into meat by rotating the mincer's handle in the opposite direction

The best option is to reinstall the previous OS **after doing the backups**. [Gilles details a method](https://askubuntu.com/a/3675/169736) that might end up breaking your system, and he warns you about it; I personally won't recommend that path.